# How to find lim of $x$ to infinity for $\sin$ fraction?

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin 15x}{4x}$$

I think the process is to sub infinity into the fraction, so $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Is this right? If so, does that simplify to zero or infinity?

Comment: For real $y,$  $|\sin y|\le1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$sin(15x)$ is a bounded function, between -1 to 1 for all x, whereas $4x$ goes to infinity as x goes to infinity. So the limit will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint $-1\leq \sin(15x)\leq 1$ so numerator is just oscillating while denominator is approaching huge values so answer is $0$

Comment: How is it determined that −1≤sin(15x)≤1?

Comment: Range of $sin(\theta)$ is from -1,1 as $sin(270)=-1$ minima,$sin(90)=1 $ maxima

Comment: Does that mean I sub it into the fraction, for -1,1 / 4x? How does that equal zero? Shouldn't it be -1/4 and 1/4?

Comment: Where is $x$ going . I think you should first see where 1/x goes as x approaches infinity